# Assets upload button disabled for members

Tags: assets, add-on, pixelandtonic

I'm having a peculiar issue:

Assets works just fine when you're logged in as a super-admin, but when you're logged in as a member, the **"upload files" button is disabled.**

I have no idea what's causing this:

there is only 1 upload directory, and the "members" member group is **allowed to upload** to this directory ( through file upload preferences ).

Furthermore, this member group has access to every part of the CP, **no restrictions** what-so-ever ( all the privileges in the member group settings are set to "yes" )

What am I missing ?

Comment: I cant comment, not enough rep so posting in here. Did you sort this? I am having the same problem! :/ Cheers, Wes.